# Iframe not work with chrome

Tags: single-sign-on, iframe

I have a mistake with iframe. This is it

The URL is built in Apex controller and return the URL Login into the external website. My problem is that the login not works now but few weeks ago it worked. The iframe shows the login screen of the external site but not do the login.

I add the site to the CSP Trusted Sites in Salesforce but still not work.

This only occurs with Chrome, in the other browsers it works fine and do the login correctly,

Any idea?

A lot of thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the errors generated in the browser's console? This is probably a frame source issue, which would normally be resolved using CSP Trusted Sites, but sounds like that didn't work for you, so check the actual error the browser generates.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your answer. The error is this: Content Security Policy of your site blocks some resources.

Some resources are blocked because their origin is not listed in your site's Content Security Policy (CSP). Your site's CSP is allowlist-based, so resources must be listed in the allowlist in order to be accessed.
A site's Content Security Policy is set either as via an HTTP header (recommended), or via a meta HTML tag.

Comment: (Recommended) If you're using an allowlist for 'script-src', consider switching from an allowlist CSP to a strict CSP, because strict CSPs are more robust against XSS . See how to set a strict CSP .
Or carefully check that all of the blocked resources are trustworthy; if they are, include their sources in the CSP of your site. ⚠️Never add a source you don't trust to your site's CSP. If you don't trust the source, consider hosting resources on your own site instead.

Comment: I am guessing this would have something to do with `sandbox` attribute on `iframe` tag

Comment: Hi @manjit5190. I try to add this attribute with all values but not work. The logging only works if i open a pop up outside Salesforce. Inside Salesforce i cant get it works.